# I don't know why I get this 'literal does not match format string', can someone tell me?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Flight
(
    FlightDate DATE,
    RouteNo CHAR(6),
    AirplaneSerialNo CHAR(6),
    ActualTD TIMESTAMP,
    ActualTA TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT FlightPK1 PRIMARY KEY (FlightDate, RouteNo),
    CONSTRAINT FlightFK1 FOREIGN KEY (RouteNo)
            REFERENCES ROUTE(RouteNo),
    CONSTRAINT FlightFK2 FOREIGN KEY (AirplaneSerialNo)
            REFERENCES Airplane(AirplaneSerialNo)
);

CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
    ReservationNo NUMBER(3),
    CustomerNo NUMBER(4),
    RouteNo CHAR(6),
    FlightDate DATE,
    Fare NUMBER(6,2),
    PaymentMethod VARCHAR2(60),
    CreditCardNumber VARCHAR2(60),
    CreditCardExpiry VARCHAR2(60),
    CONSTRAINT ReservationPK1 PRIMARY KEY (ReservationNo),
    CONSTRAINT ReservationFK1 FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNo)
            REFERENCES Customer(CustomerNo),
    CONSTRAINT FlightFK5 FOREIGN KEY (FlightDate,RouteNo)
            REFERENCES Flight(FlightDate,RouteNo),
    CONSTRAINT Reservation 
            CHECK (PaymentMethod IN ('Cash', 'CreditCard'))
);

INSERT INTO RESERVATION 
VALUES ('001', '001', 'FBN001', '2021-06-20', '', 'Cash', '', '');
```

and the result comes out literal does not match the format string
Does anyone know this?. Btw, it comes out primary key not found after I set the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely your date: `'2021-06-20'`, which I'm guessing doesn't match your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` initialization parameter. You can override the default by using the `TO_DATE` function in your insert and supplying your own format template:

```
INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES 
(1, 1, 'FBN001', TO_DATE('2021-06-20','YYYY-MM-DD'), '', 'Cash', '', '');
```

Comment: parent key cant found after enter it hmmmm

Comment: number data types cannot have leading zeros - the text you entered probably didn't match the actual key of the parent table. I have edited the insert to account for the first two columns being actual numbers.